# boost::log format doesn't work when called from DLL

Tags: c++, logging, boost, dll, boost-log

I used to format output of `boost::log` in a DLL of mine, named *libfoo* and used by a Win32 console application *exefoo*. Code is

```
// #include various boost log headers

void __declspec(dllexport) add_boost_log_console_sink()
{
    boost::log::add_common_attributes();

    boost::shared_ptr<text_sink> sink = boost::make_shared<text_sink>();

    sink->locked_backend()->add_stream(boost::shared_ptr<std::ostream>(&std::cout, boost::null_deleter()));

    sink->set_formatter(xspectra::get_our_formatter(false));

    sink->set_filter(boost::log::trivial::severity >= boost::log::trivial::info
        &&
        boost::log::expressions::has_attr(tag_attr) == false);

    boost::log::core::get()->add_sink(sink);
}

boost::log::formatter __declspec(dllexport) get_our_formatter(bool bSubSeconds)
{
    std::string sTimeStamp("%H:%M:%S");
    if (bSubSeconds)
        sTimeStamp += ".%f";

    return boost::log::expressions::stream
        //<< std::hex  //To print the LineID in Hexadecimal format
        << std::setw(6) << std::setfill('0')
        << line_id
        << "\t"
        << boost::log::expressions::format_date_time<boost::posix_time::ptime>("TimeStamp", sTimeStamp)
        << " <" << boost::log::trivial::severity
        << ">  \t"
        /*
                    << boost::log::expressions::if_(boost::log::expressions::has_attr(tag_attr))
                    [
                        boost::log::expressions::stream << "[" << tag_attr << "]\t"         TAGS SUSPENDED
                    ]
        */
        << boost::log::expressions::smessage;
}
```

In the main, exposed object of *libfoo*, I was calling -once- `add_boost_log_console_sink();` same call inside the `main()` of *exefoo*.

Every subsequent `BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(severity)` call **inside** *libfoo* was producing formatted output, while every similar call inside *exefoo* was not.

For code modularity purposes, I moved these functions into a new DLL, *liblog*, used by *libfoo* and *exefoo*. Now every log is **not** formatted.

It seems that having this code loaded from a DLL somehow doesn't produce any effect; I wish it would do.

Comment: Do you link with Boost.Log dynamically (i.e. dlls)? Do you define `BOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK` or `BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK`?

Comment: I don't, I'm linking statically against `libboost_log-vc140-mt-1_60.lib`. But *liblog* and *libfoo* are dlls. Maybe I should change at least *liblog* to static lib.

Comment: That's the source of the problem. Boost.Log requires to be built as a shared library if used from different modules. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/installation/config.html

Answer (score 0):

As an insight provided by [Andrey Semashev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4636534/andrey-semashev), i switched *liblog* Configuration Type from dynamic to static library. Now everything works fine.